# Receiving incomplete messages on Whatsapp?

Tags: whatsapp-messenger

I am currently using HTC Desire C. Yup, a pretty old model..almost 3 years old now! Lately, I've been having problems on Whatsapp that I don't see anyone else having so I'm wondering if its my phone's fault.

Firstly, every time I open Whatsapp after switching on the Wifi or switching on the phone (say, if the battery died), error message 'Whatsapp is not responding' appears. And not until I press 'Okay' atleast 6-10 times  (not exaggerating) in response to the same message appearing again and again, Whatsapp finally opens and it takes another 5 minutes to start receiving the messages.

And of the received messages, most of them are incomplete (as in, I receive say, 1 out of 5 sent messages) or I don't receive messages from certain people at all (when they said they have).

Is there anything I can do to solve this? I'm desperate!

Comment: Try updating whatsapp

Answer (score 1):

All you can do is:

1. Reset your phone.
2. Try uninstalling the app and delete all files connected with WhatsApp, then reinstall.
3. Install a custom ROM which is good choice for you.